# Impossible to compile Fortran code with include statement

Tags: unix, include, fortran, gfortran

I have a script "simul.f" that starts with a line

```
include 'support.f'
```

and I also have the "support.f" script. The line showed above is the only line that call the support.f, so I tried to compile both of them using:

```
gfortran -o executable support.f simul.f
```

and I get the following error:

> /home/pmachado3/LarryProject Oficial/WI1_francisco/T2/WI4/FF04/04-1$ gfortran -o exec support.f simul.f
>   /tmp/ccOicDhk.o: In function `support_':
>   simul.f:(.text+0x0): multiple definition of`support_'
>   /tmp/ccnkwMCD.o:support.f:(.text+0x0): first defined here
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I made a test and tried to remove the line include from simul.f and it compiled however did not generate my output file .txt that should generate

Is there any way to compile the code in Unix with the include line??

The code works fine on Windows and was written in Force 2.0

Comment: So where is the include file located?

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38839371/gfortran-makefile-cant-open-included-file

Comment: If it is in the same directory it should be found automatically. No `-I.` should be necessary.

Comment: Actually, if the file contains only stand-alone external procedures you could use it either way, an "include" statement or list it separately on the compile command line ( either way but not both  )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just compile the file that contains the include statement

```
 gfortran -o executable simul.f
```

and the `include` is performed by the compiler automatically.

If the included file is in some other directory `path` you must tell the compiler where that path is

```
 gfortran -o executable simul.f -Ipath
```

Comment: So it would identify the support.f even in unix? I tought it should be compiled too. Well I tried and I am able to compile the simul.f and execute that however it does not generate me any output file. If i a code similar that needs no include it generates successfully

Comment: Yes, without support.f even in Unix.  I have no idea why the code I cannot see does not generate something. It is likely some other problem for a different question anyway.  I recommend to just copy and paste `support.f` to the main file instead of the `include "support.f"` for your tests. If it doesn't work even after the paste, it is a different problem. Prepare a [mcve] and ask a new question.

Comment: If it failed to find the file to include it would simply not compile. I think whatever problem you have is unrelated to the include.

Comment: I tried again and worked like a charm. Thank you so much @VladimirF